# Which dmv can help identify the cost of index maintenance for exisitng and missing indexes?

Tags: sql-server, dmv, index-maintenance

I want to identity:

1. Indexes that are costly to maintain.
2. Missing indexes along with their maintenance cost.

By maintenance I mean - the index maintenance during insert/update/delete.

Which dmv can help me get this info?

There are a couple columns in sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats like: avg_total_user_cost, avg_user_impact but they are about the query rather than maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question could be very broad as it depends upon the  workload of Sql server where you want to do index tuning. A good starting point would be SP_BlitzIndex ( link https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitzindex-tune-your-indexes) . It has various modes which you can use based on what you are trying to achieve .

I would say track the usage of index over a period of time . Again that period depends upon the workload using those indexes, like there could be weekly, monthly or even yearly reports. Once you store the metrics over a period of time , you will gain some confidence on the indexes which are duplicates and not getting used. You can simply remove them based on your trending data which should help you with question- indexes that are costly to maintain.

For your second question as well, those missing index recommendations need to be well analyzed so that you don’t end up adding duplicate or partial duplicate indexes. What indexes you currently have and what type of index maintenance you do will drive your second question .

This might not be perfect answer you looking for, but highly recommend analyzing the queries and indexes already out there over a period of time to get better understanding before you move with action items and trust me sp_blitzindex  procedure should help as I have done lot of index tuning with help of it, rather than re-inventing the wheel .